# Can I run Jupyter Notebook instead of Databricks?

Tags: python, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, databricks

Is it possible to run the codes from Databricks on a Jupyter Notebook without calling the DB cluster? I know there's an application for VScode but I'd like to try on Jupyter Notebook.

I want to run all the cells on my computer (using local processing) and when it's done I would just transfer it to Databricks. This way I would not have cluster consumption on testing codes.

Comment: You can setup a spark cluster locally, mock the necessary data, develop your code in jupyter notebooks and then transfer it to databricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Databricks has [an article](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/ci-cd/ci-cd-jenkins.html) on CI/CD that describes how you can develop in once place and then push you code to Databricks using their [command line tool](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/workspace-cli.html).

With this, you can develop locally in Jupyter and then just push to databricks when you're done.